# Distributed Tensorflow on multiple machines not scaling up

Tags: deep-learning, distributed-computing, tensorflow

I am trying to run a distributed Tensorflow job that trains a deep convolutional MNIST classifier. I have combined the deep convolutional mnist classifier in:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py and distributed mnist in: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py

The code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import math
import sys
import logging

import time
import os.path
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string("data_dir", "/tmp/mnist-data",
                    "Directory for storing mnist data")
flags.DEFINE_string("train_dir", "/tmp/train",
                    "Directory for storing train logs")
flags.DEFINE_boolean("download_only", False,
                     "Only perform downloading of data; Do not proceed to "
                     "session preparation, model definition or training")
flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", None,
                     "Worker task index, should be >= 0. task_index=0 is "
                     "the master worker task the performs the variable "
                     "initialization ")
flags.DEFINE_integer("num_gpus", 1,
                     "Total number of gpus for each machine."
                     "If you don't use GPU, please set it to '0'")
flags.DEFINE_integer("replicas_to_aggregate", None,
                     "Number of replicas to aggregate before parameter update"
                     "is applied (For sync_replicas mode only; default: "
                     "num_workers)")
flags.DEFINE_integer("hidden_units", 100,
                     "Number of units in the hidden layer of the NN")
flags.DEFINE_integer("train_steps", 200,
                     "Number of (global) training steps to perform")
flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 100, "Training batch size")
flags.DEFINE_float("learning_rate", 0.01, "Learning rate")
flags.DEFINE_boolean("sync_replicas", False,
                     "Use the sync_replicas (synchronized replicas) mode, "
                     "wherein the parameter updates from workers are aggregated "
                     "before applied to avoid stale gradients")
flags.DEFINE_boolean(
    "existing_servers", False, "Whether servers already exists. If True, "
    "will use the worker hosts via their GRPC URLs (one client process "
    "per worker host). Otherwise, will create an in-process TensorFlow "
    "server.")
flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts","localhost:2222",
                    "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "localhost:2223,localhost:2224",
                    "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", None,"job name: worker or ps")

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


IMAGE_PIXELS = 28


def conv2d(x, W):
  """conv2d returns a 2d convolution layer with full stride."""
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
  """max_pool_2x2 downsamples a feature map by 2X."""
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def weight_variable(shape):
  """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
  """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def deepnn(x):

  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # First convolutional layer - maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
  W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
  b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
  h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

  # Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
  h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

  # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
  W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
  b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
  h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

  # Second pooling layer.
  h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

  # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
  # is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
  W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
  b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

  h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
  h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  # Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
  # features.
  keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

  # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
  W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
  b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

  y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
  return y_conv, keep_prob



def main(unused_argv):
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
  if FLAGS.download_only:
    sys.exit(0)

  if tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.train_dir):
    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(FLAGS.train_dir)
  tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.train_dir)

  if FLAGS.job_name is None or FLAGS.job_name == "":
    raise ValueError("Must specify an explicit `job_name`")
  if FLAGS.task_index is None or FLAGS.task_index =="":
    raise ValueError("Must specify an explicit `task_index`")

  print("job name = %s" % FLAGS.job_name)
  print("task index = %d" % FLAGS.task_index)

  #Construct the cluster and start the server
  ps_spec = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_spec = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Get the number of workers.
  num_workers = len(worker_spec)

  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({
      "ps": ps_spec,
      "worker": worker_spec})

  if not FLAGS.existing_servers:
    # Not using existing servers. Create an in-process server.
    server = tf.train.Server(
        cluster, job_name=FLAGS.job_name, task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
      server.join()

  is_chief = (FLAGS.task_index == 0)
  if FLAGS.num_gpus > 0:
    gpu = (FLAGS.task_index % FLAGS.num_gpus)
    worker_device = "/job:worker/task:%d/gpu:%d" % (FLAGS.task_index, gpu)
  elif FLAGS.num_gpus == 0:
    # Just allocate the CPU to worker server
    cpu = 0
    worker_device = "/job:worker/task:%d/cpu:%d" % (FLAGS.task_index, cpu)

  with tf.device(
      tf.train.replica_device_setter(
          worker_device=worker_device,
          ps_device="/job:ps/cpu:0",
          cluster=cluster)):
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMAGE_PIXELS*IMAGE_PIXELS])

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    if FLAGS.sync_replicas:
      if FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate is None:
        replicas_to_aggregate = num_workers
      else:
        replicas_to_aggregate = FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate

      opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(
          opt,
          replicas_to_aggregate=replicas_to_aggregate,
          total_num_replicas=num_workers,
          name="mnist_sync_replicas")

    train_step = opt.minimize(cross_entropy, global_step=global_step)

    if FLAGS.sync_replicas:
      local_init_op = opt.local_step_init_op
      if is_chief:
        local_init_op = opt.chief_init_op

      ready_for_local_init_op = opt.ready_for_local_init_op

      # Initial token and chief queue runners required by the sync_replicas mode
      chief_queue_runner = opt.get_chief_queue_runner()
      sync_init_op = opt.get_init_tokens_op()

    saver=tf.train.Saver()
    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    train_dir = FLAGS.train_dir

    if FLAGS.sync_replicas:
      sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
          is_chief=is_chief,
          logdir=train_dir,
          init_op=init_op,
          local_init_op=local_init_op,
          ready_for_local_init_op=ready_for_local_init_op,
          recovery_wait_secs=1,
          global_step=global_step,
          summary_op=summary_op,
          saver=saver,
          save_model_secs=600)
    else:
      sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
          is_chief=is_chief,
          logdir=train_dir,
          init_op=init_op,
          recovery_wait_secs=1,
          global_step=global_step,
          summary_op=summary_op,
          saver=saver,
          save_model_secs=600)

    sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        log_device_placement=False,
        device_filters=["/job:ps", "/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index])

    if is_chief:
      print("Worker %d: Initializing session..." % FLAGS.task_index)

    else:
      print("Worker %d: Waiting for session to be initialized..." %
            FLAGS.task_index)

      # get TF logger
    log = logging.getLogger('tensorflow')
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    fh = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir,'tensorflow.log'))
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(fh)

    if FLAGS.existing_servers:
      server_grpc_url = "grpc://" + worker_spec[FLAGS.task_index]
      print("Using existing server at: %s" % server_grpc_url)

      sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server_grpc_url,
                                            config=sess_config)
    else:
      sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target, config=sess_config)

    print("Worker %d: Session initialization complete." % FLAGS.task_index)

    if FLAGS.sync_replicas and is_chief:
      # Chief worker will start the chief queue runner and call the init op.
      sess.run(sync_init_op)
      sv.start_queue_runners(sess, [chief_queue_runner])

    # Perform training
    time_begin = time.time()
    print("Training begins @ %s" % time.ctime(int(time_begin)))
    local_step = 0
    val_feed = {x: mnist.validation.images, y_: mnist.validation.labels,keep_prob:1.0}

    while not sv.should_stop():

      batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
      train_feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob:0.5}

      _, step = sess.run([train_step, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
      local_step += 1

      now = time.time()
      msg=("%f: Worker %d: training step %d done (global step: %d)" %
            (now, FLAGS.task_index, local_step, step))
      log.debug(msg)

      if step >= FLAGS.train_steps:
        break

    time_end = time.time()
    print("Training ends @ %s" % time.ctime(int(time_end)))
    training_time = time_end - time_begin
    print("Training elapsed time: %f s" % training_time)

    if not FLAGS.sync_replicas:
      print("Num of examples processed: %d \n" %(FLAGS.batch_size*FLAGS.train_steps))
      print("Examples per sec: %f \n "%(FLAGS.batch_size*FLAGS.train_steps*1.0/training_time))
      print("Seconds per batch: %f" % (training_time/FLAGS.train_steps))

    val_xent = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict=val_feed)
    print("After %d training step(s), validation cross entropy = %g" %
          (FLAGS.train_steps, val_xent))

    print('\ntest accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0},session=sess))

    # sv.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

I am using Tensorflow1.2.1, CUDA8.0 and cuDNN5.1. The *sync_replicas* flag is kept False and *train_steps* flag is 15000. I ran it on each worker as:

```
python mnist.py --ps_hosts=*ps_ip:port*\ 
--worker_hosts=*worker_ip-port pairs* --num_gpus=1 \
--train_steps=15000 --job_name=worker --task_index=*task_index*\ 
--train_dir=./train
```

I masked individual gpus using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` while running multiple workers on same machine.
The speed is as follows:

- One g2.8xlarge machine (ps on cpu and workers on gpus(each worker occupying 1 gpu)):

  - 1 worker:- Training time: 1085 sec, 1381 examples/sec
  - 2 workers:- Training time: 547 sec, 2741 examples/sec
  - 3 workers:- Training time: 389 sec, 3855 examples/sec

But with one ps on m3.xlarge and multiple workers each on a g2.2xlarge machine (all of them are in the same zone), the speed is:

- 1 worker:- Training Time: 2313 sec, 648 examples/sec
- 2 workers:- Training Time: 2290 sec, 654 examples/sec
- 3 workers:- Training Time: 2291 sec, 654 examples/sec

Why is it not scaling up when I use workers on multiple machines but scales up all right when used on the same machine with workers on different gpus? I also used m3.2xlarge as my ps to see if the ps(cpu or its bandwidth) is the bottleneck, but it still did not scale up(although the overall training time reduced to 1604 sec).

Also, while running on the same machine, `nvidia-smi` shows that the gpu usage for each gpu is around 30% while it is around 13% when run on multiple machines.

Comment: have you tried multiple PS?

Comment: @lejlot I am afraid that didn't work as well.